# VB.NET reading doc and docx files

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have to read doc and docx files with text, image, table, bullets etc(everything)

I want to display the content of file in same order(if image on the top then text and then a table).

Please let me know how to read so I can get whole content. I can read only text from doc and docx file but cannot read whole content.

I used below code to read only text, Please advise how to read whole content with tables and images.

I used below code to read only text, Please advise how to read whole content with tables and images.

My code looks like below:

```
  Dim WordApp As New Word.ApplicationClass
            'Dim filepath = Server.MapPath("~/files/Hello2.doc")
            Dim File As Object = filename
            Dim nullobj As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
            Dim doc As Word.Document = WordApp.Documents.Open(File, nullobj, nullobj, nullobj, nullobj, nullobj, nullobj, nullobj, nullobj, nullobj, nullobj, nullobj)
            'Dim doc1 As Word.Document = WordApp.ActiveDocument
            Dim m_Content As String = doc.Content.Text
```

Comment: HTML editor.. thats doesnt make since as the datatype isnt the same... what do you really want to do?

Comment: I can read text from file but I want to read everything including images, tables.. everything ... please guide..

Answer (score 0):

I would download and install the OpenXML 2.5 library -

You should be able to read all the contents of the document fairly inituitively. Here's some documentation: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc850833.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any graceful way to achieve this.  As mentioned in the comments, different datatypes.

You're going to have to get the text out (you said you can already do this), then separately get the images.  Then format them or whatever you want to do.

Never tried this, but found this link.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msdnmagazine/archive/2007/05/15/2649901.aspx